# How to boot Windows 7 (installed with WinToUSB) from external HDD?

Tags: windows-7, boot, external-hard-drive

Here is how I setup Windows 7 on the external HDD:

1. I used `WinToUSB` to install Windows 7;
2. I selected the same partition (`L:\`) in `the system partition` and `the boot partition` options.
3. I wait until it finished installing Windows 7.

Then I tried to change the first boot priority to the external HDD but a black screen showed up after BIOS checking.

Next I tried commands like `bcdboot L:\Windows`, `bootsect /NT60 L:`, `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`. Neither changing boot priority to internal HDD nor changing boot priority to external HDD boots Windows 7 on the exernal HDD.

I have checked the external HDD with `MiniTool Partition Wizard`' s surface test with no problem, also checked that partition `L:` is `Primary` type not `Logical` and is `active`.

Would someone show me how to install Windows 7 to external HDD and boot Windows 7 from it?

**EDIT:** `WinToUSB` used legacy method to install Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read and found your best bet is to use Windows 8 as that supports what you would like to do.

If Windows 8 is out of the question then try using something like Virtual Box Portable. That should help in what you are trying to achieve.

> VirtualBox must normally be installed to run. As a virtual machine program, it needs to install Windows kernel drivers and system services. Like most programs, it also saves its settings in system areas. It can’t just be installed to a USB drive and run on any computer you come across.
>
> Portable VirtualBox is a wrapper for VirtualBox that turns it into a
>   portable application you can install on a USB stick or external hard
>   drive. When you launch Portable VirtualBox on a computer, it will
>   automatically install the appropriate drivers and system services —
>   administrator access is required for this — and automatically
>   uninstall them from the computer when you’re done. It also provides a
>   graphical interface for downloading VirtualBox, setting it up in a
>   portable environment, and changing its options.
>
> Portable VirtualBox is designed to run on Windows host PCs, so don’t
>   expect it to run on Linux or Mac host systems.

---

Guide:

> Step 1: First of all, connect your USB to the machine and backup all
>   the data from the USB drive.
>
> Step 2: Download VirtualBox portable, double-click on the executable
>   file and extract the contents to your USB.
>
> install windows 7 on usb
>
> Step 3: Now, go to the VirtualBox portable folder in USB, and execute
>   the Portable-VirtualBox (.exe) file.
>
> Step 4: From here onwards, you need to follow the onscreen procedure
>   to create a virtual disk and install Windows 7 on USB. Follow the
>   install Windows 7 on VirtualBox guide to complete the process.
>
> Step 5: Once you finish the installation process, you can safely close
>   VirtualBox and remove your USB drive.
>
> Step 6: You can now use this Windows 7 USB drive on any Windows
>   machine that you want. To use Windows 7 on other machine, connect the
>   Windows 7 USB, open USB drive, and run portable-VirtualBox file.

These 2 links should help in what you are looking for.

http://www.vbox.me/

http://www.intowindows.com/install-windows-7-on-usb/

Answer (score 0):

WinToUSB is a tool to install Windows 8 on an external drive. It should not work on Windows 7. So that's probably why it's failing to boot.

As TheNerdyNerd pointed out, Into Windows can help you with your problem:
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-to-usb-external-hard-drive-must-read/

Comment: The software says it can install Windows 7. I may use the wrong software as there is a thingy called `WinToHDD`. I am trying it now, thanks anyway.